# Shifting rows only in specific columns

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to shift rows down in my excel sheet and insert new data to the top of the list.
I'm able to shift rows down as:

```
int row = getItemsListSize(); <- which returns size of the list which contains elements
sheet.shiftRows(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), rows);
```

Then I insert new data starting from row 1 and that way newest data is always on top of the list and older data gets moved down.

My problem is that I have second table also on that sheet and amount of items inside it isn't same as in first table. Currently also contents of this table gets moved down although no new items aren't added. Because of that it looks weird.

Is there way to only shift rows inside specific columns? For example: Move rows only in columns A-D.

Answer (score 1):

No; from an excel perspective, there is no such thing as two separate tables. It's just one big sheet with rows and columns. Apache POI is a library that gives you access to excel's data structures. It's not a generalized 'mess with sheets' library. You'd have to write the code for such such a thing yourself.

More generally you're misusing excel a bit. The right move usually is to treat data, as, well, data. You should not be having 2 unrelated tables on the same sheet. Use the + button at the bottom left (or the appropriate POI option, which also supports sheets) to add another sheet.

If you want a sheet for visual reasons, make a *third* sheet, and that is a sheet that your POI code should never touch - it will render the data from the other (data) sheets. You can now add graphs, logos, whatever you want, and you won't run into issues where moving things around a bit 'because it looks nicer visually' then results in your POI-based code being broken.